# Streaming remote file to other remote server

Tags: php, curl

I need to download large file from url and upload this file to another server.
It is possible with PHP without saving on disk/RAM?
I know the `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` and `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, but how to use their
 both?

Comment: Try using wget linux command in PHP

<?php
exec("wget -P local_path remote_path_url")
?>                                  NOTE: you need linux server and executable permission to run this in php

Comment: In order to download you have to store the file in anywhere of your system. Some program store file in a temporary path like ```/temp``` than deletes it.

Comment: @Nadeshwaran, yes, now i see only that option: `curl http://example.com/down | curl -T - ftp://mysite.org/up`